# Pandas replace row with grpupby sum

Tags: pandas

I have a sample DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 1)), columns=list('A'))
df["B"] = ["apple","apple","orange","orange","orange"]
df
```

Op:

```
    A    B
 0  4   apple
 1  2   apple
 2  2   orange
 3  1   orange
 4  8   orange
```

I am trying to replace the column B values with sum (groupby(B))

```
df.groupby("B")["A"].sum()
```

OP:

```
B
apple      6
orange    11
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Expected OP:

```
    A   B
0   4   6
1   2   6
2   2   11
3   1   11
4   8   11
```

I am currently using an iterative solution to do that. Is there a more concise pandas approach. Any suggestion on the APPROACH would be great.

Comment: Use groupby with transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `transform` `sum`

```
df.groupby('B').A.transform('sum')
0     7
1     7
2    12
3    12
4    12
Name: A, dtype: int32
#df['new']=df.groupby('B').A.transform('sum')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this without transform use GroupBy, Sum + map
Try this,

```
df["B"]=df["B"].map(df.groupby("B")["A"].sum())
```

Input:

```
   A       B
0  9   apple
1  2   apple
2  3  orange
3  8  orange
4  9  orange
```

Output:

```
   A   B
0  9  11
1  2  11
2  3  20
3  8  20
4  9  20
```